# PowerShell handling spaces in string when opening Excel spreadsheet

Tags: powershell

I've been struggling with this for a while, I have tried to add double and single quotes to the string, and I have tried to add multiple quotes etc..

It's actually quite simple, I need to open a spreadsheet with space in the name like this:

Code:

```
function convert_xlst_to_xls([string]$File) {
    $Filepath = Get-Item -Path $File
    $NewFilepath = Join-Path -Path $FilePath.Directory.FullName -ChildPath "$($Filepath.BaseName).xls"

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $true #or false
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('$Filepath'.FullName, [Type]::Missing, $true)
    $Workbook.SaveAs("$NewFilepath", 56)
    $Workbook.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
    Remove-Variable Excel
    return "$NewFilepath"
}

$covertedFile = convert_xlst_to_xls('c:\my documents\ubi\new template 
template.xlsx')
```

When I run this it splits op the file name and attempt to open a spreadsheet with the name new.xlst.

How can I handle those filenames with spaces in PowerShell within a string variable.

Comment: `'$Filepath'` is incorrect. PowerShell will not expand variables in single quotes, and even if it did, the resulting string wouldn't have a property `FullName`. Remove the quotes from `'$Filepath'` and `"$NewFilepath"`. Also, there's a newline in the path in your last statement that shouldn't be there. Is that in your actual code or did you just mistype that in your question?

Comment: Thanks, it worked seems that i had been looking to much at qoutes making me blind  to mos simple solutio.